# The sign of the modulo operator result?

Tags: c, modulo

I have couple line of C code testing the modulo operator as follows:

```
// line 1
printf("%d\n", 5 % (-3)); => output: 2
// line 2
printf("%d\n", -5 % 3); => output: -2
```

I know that the sign of the modulo depends on the sign of the numerator, but I am curious why not otherwise?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6385400/253056

Comment: This is not a question to vote down. It is a question of how the modulo operator works, and is a good question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the result of pretty much any combination of `%` and negative numbers is implementation-defined.

Comment: It's implementation-defined prior to C99 - see previous duplicates

Answer (score 3):

```
5/(-3) = -1;
(-5)/3 = -1; 

If that is agreed then let's calculate the remainder

Remainder = Dividend - ( Divisor * Factor)

5 - (-3 * -1) = 2
-5 - (3 * -1) = -2
```